# how to open a file in a folder and search a particular string in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

Need:  Open a folder that have a name ending with today's date and searching a particular string and returning the entire line of that particular string if found in c#

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ helps to simpify this task:

```
var allMatchingLines = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir)
    .Where(fn => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).EndsWith(DateTime.Today.ToString("d")))
    .SelectMany(fn => File.ReadLines(fn).Where(l => l.Contains(searchString)));
```

[just saw that the folder name should contain the date, then remove the `Where`]